# Laravel Route group change which view is used for guests and members

Tags: php, laravel

I'm currently trying to figure out the URL routing in Laravel, I have the basic pages working but I'm trying to figure out the best way to distinguish between guests and members.

The aim is to have the index page user splash view for guests and if a user is logged in then use the dashboard view.

Like this:

```
Route::group(array('before' => 'guest'), function()
{
    Route::get('/', function()
    {    
        return View::make('splash');
    })); 
});

Route::group(array('after' => 'auth'), function()
{
    Route::get('/', function()
    {    
        return View::make('dashboard');
    })); 
});
```

At the moment this doesn't work as it always seems to try and display the authenticated `'after' => 'auth'` page even when a user is not logged in?

Comment: there is also a `guest` filter, `Route::group(array('before' => 'guest'), function()`

Comment: the `after` filter works differently, you will not need it in this scenario at all. Change line 9 back to `Route::group(array('before' => 'auth'), function()`

Comment: If I do that then the page always redirects to login. I want to have a splash for guests on `/` and then different content for users after logging in on `/`

Comment: But you get it all wrong. I would suggest you some step by step tutorial, lets say http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/authentication-with-laravel-4--net-35593 is really detailed.

Comment: `auth` before filter is used to *protect* routes from unauthenticated users. `guest` beore filter is used to protect login and sometimes a registration from already logged in user. if you want to check if user is logged in, then `Auth::check()` is for that purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to different views for the same route depending on whether logged in or not you just define the route once and in the closure check to see if the user is logged in and then return the relevant view

```
Route::get('/', function()
{
    if (Auth::check())
        return View::make('dashboard');

    return View::make('splash');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this may get you closer to the solution, but it will still not work, there is more work to do then just showing Views. Also, if you want to show different content on route '/' for auth users and guest users, you cannot use filter.

```
Route::group(array('before' => 'guest'), function()
{
    Route::get('login', function()
    {    
        return View::make('users.login');
    })); 
});

//~ Route::group(array('before' => 'auth'), function()
//~ {
    Route::get('/', function()
    {   
        // if user is logged in
        if (Auth::check())
            return View::make('dashboard');
        else
            return View::make('splash');
    })); 
//~ });
```